Python csv error when creating .exe file cx_freeze
I have a python project with the following files:

main.py
1.py
2.py
images (folder with a bunch of pngs)
testFiles (folder with a few files for unit tests)

the way the project works, main is a script that uses methods and pictures from 1 2 and images. The program works properly when I run it on my IDE, but for some reason I can't use cx_freeze to make it a .exe file
everytime I try to run python setup.py build in the terminal I get the following error:
AttributeError: module 'cv2.gapi.wip' has no attribute '__path__'. Did you mean: '__name__'?
i tried import cv2 in a couple files, and uninstalling and re installing cv2 and none of it has worked. What should I do?
not sure if it's relevant but i'm working on windows 11
edit - here is the whole terminal output:

running build
running build_exe
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\user\Desktop\project\setup.py", line 29, in 
setup(
File > "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.11_qbz5n2kfra8> p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python311\site-packages\cx_Freeze_init_.py", line 67, in > setup
return setuptools.setup(**attrs)
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File > "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.11_qbz5n2kfra8> p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python311\site-packages\setuptools_init_.py", line 103, in > setup
return distutils.core.setup(**attrs)
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File > "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.11_qbz5n2kfra8> p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python311\site-packages\setuptools_distutils\core.py", line > 184, in setup
return run_commands(dist)
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File > "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.11_qbz5n2kfra8> p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python311\site-packages\setuptools_distutils\core.py", line 200, > in run_commands
dist.run_commands()
File > "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.11_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python311\site-packages\setuptools_distutils\dist.py", line 969, > in run_commands
self.run_command(cmd)
File > "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.11_qbz5n2kfra8> p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python311\site-packages\setuptools\dist.py", line 976, in > run_command
super().run_command(command)
File > "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.11_qbz5n2kfra8> p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python311\site-packages\setuptools_distutils\dist.py", line 988, > in run_command
cmd_obj.run()
File > "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.11_qbz5n2kfra8> p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python311\site-packages\setuptools_distutils\command\build.p> y", line 132, in run
self.run_command(cmd_name)
File > "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.11_qbz5n2kfra8> p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python311\site-packages\setuptools_distutils\cmd.py", line > 316, in run_command
self.distribution.run_command(command)
File > "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.11_qbz5n2kfra8> p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python311\site-packages\setuptools\dist.py", line 976, in > run_command
super().run_command(command)
File > "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.11_qbz5n2kfra8> p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python311\site-packages\setuptools_distutils\dist.py", line 988, > in run_command
cmd_obj.run()
File > "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.11_qbz5n2kfra8> p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python311\site-packages\cx_Freeze\command\build_exe.py", > line 282, in run
freezer: Freezer = Freezer(
^^^^^^^^
File > "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.11_qbz5n2kfra8> p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python311\site-packages\cx_Freeze\freezer.py", line 791, in > init
Freezer.init(self, *args, **kwargs)
File > "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.11_qbz5n2kfra8> p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python311\site-packages\cx_Freeze\freezer.py", line 134, in > init
self.finder: ModuleFinder = self._get_module_finder()
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File > "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.11_qbz5n2kfra8> p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python311\site-packages\cx_Freeze\freezer.py", line 392, in > _get_module_finder
finder.include_module(name)
File > "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.11_qbz5n2kfra8> p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python311\site-packages\cx_Freeze\finder.py", line 794, in > include_module
module = self._import_module(name, deferred_imports)
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File > "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.11_qbz5n2kfra8> p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python311\site-packages\cx_Freeze\finder.py", line 268, in > _import_module
module = self._internal_import_module(name, deferred_imports)
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File > "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.11_qbz5n2kfra8> p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python311\site-packages\cx_Freeze\finder.py", line 338, in > _internal_import_module
parent_module = self._internal_import_module(
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File > "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.11_qbz5n2kfra8> p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python311\site-packages\cx_Freeze\finder.py", line 355, in > _internal_import_module
module = self._load_module(
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File > "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.11_qbz5n2kfra8> p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python311\site-packages\cx_Freeze\finder.py", line 422, in > _load_module
self._load_module_code(module, loader, deferred_imports)
File > "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.11_qbz5n2kfra8> p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python311\site-packages\cx_Freeze\finder.py", line 472, in > _load_module_code
self._scan_code(module, deferred_imports)
File > "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.11_qbz5n2kfra8> p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python311\site-packages\cx_Freeze\finder.py", line 664, in > _scan_code
imported_module = self._import_module(
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File > "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.11_qbz5n2kfra8> p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python311\site-packages\cx_Freeze\finder.py", line 268, in > _import_module
module = self._internal_import_module(name, deferred_imports)
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File > "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.11_qbz5n2kfra8> p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python311\site-packages\cx_Freeze\finder.py", line 355, in > _internal_import_module
module = self._load_module(
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File > "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.11_qbz5n2kfra8> p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python311\site-packages\cx_Freeze\finder.py", line 422, in > _load_module
self._load_module_code(module, loader, deferred_imports)
File > "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.11_qbz5n2kfra8> p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python311\site-packages\cx_Freeze\finder.py", line 472, in > _load_module_code
self._scan_code(module, deferred_imports)
File > "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.11_qbz5n2kfra8> p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python311\site-packages\cx_Freeze\finder.py", line 664, in > _scan_code
imported_module = self._import_module(
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File > "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.11_qbz5n2kfra8> p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python311\site-packages\cx_Freeze\finder.py", line 268, in > _import_module
module = self._internal_import_module(name, deferred_imports)
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File > "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.11_qbz5n2kfra8> p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python311\site-packages\cx_Freeze\finder.py", line 355, in > _internal_import_module
module = self._load_module(
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File > "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.11_qbz5n2kfra8> p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python311\site-packages\cx_Freeze\finder.py", line 422, in > _load_module
self._load_module_code(module, loader, deferred_imports)
File > "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.11_qbz5n2kfra8> p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python311\site-packages\cx_Freeze\finder.py", line 472, in > _load_module_code
self._scan_code(module, deferred_imports)
File > "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.11_qbz5n2kfra8> p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python311\site-packages\cx_Freeze\finder.py", line 664, in > _scan_code
imported_module = self._import_module(
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File > "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.11_qbz5n2kfra8vp0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python311\site-packages\cx_Freeze\finder.py", line 268, in > _import_module
module = self._internal_import_module(name, deferred_imports)
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File > "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.11_qbz5n2kfra8> p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python311\site-packages\cx_Freeze\finder.py", line 355, in > _internal_import_module
module = self._load_module(
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File > "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.11_qbz5n2kfra8> p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python311\site-packages\cx_Freeze\finder.py", line 422, in > _load_module
self._load_module_code(module, loader, deferred_imports)
File > "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.11_qbz5n2kfra8> p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python311\site-packages\cx_Freeze\finder.py", line 465, in > _load_module_code
module.hook(self)
File > "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.11_qbz5n2kfra8> p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python311\site-packages\cx_Freeze\hooks\cv2.py", line 60, in > load_cv2
finder.include_package("cv2")
File > "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.11_qbz5n2kfra8> p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python311\site-packages\cx_Freeze\finder.py", line 805, in > include_package
self._import_all_sub_modules(module, deferred_imports)
File > "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.11_qbz5n2kfra8> p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python311\site-packages\cx_Freeze\finder.py", line 223, in > _import_all_sub_modules
sub_module = self._internal_import_module(
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File > "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.11_qbz5n2kfra8> p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python311\site-packages\cx_Freeze\finder.py", line 355, in > _internal_import_module
module = self._load_module(
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File > "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.11_qbz5n2kfra8> p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python311\site-packages\cx_Freeze\finder.py", line 422, in > _load_module
self._load_module_code(module, loader, deferred_imports)
File > "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.11_qbz5n2kfra8> p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python311\site-packages\cx_Freeze\finder.py", line 472, in > _load_module_code
self._scan_code(module, deferred_imports)
File > "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.11_qbz5n2kfra8> p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python311\site-packages\cx_Freeze\finder.py", line 664, in > _scan_code
imported_module = self._import_module(
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File > "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.11_qbz5n2kfra8> p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python311\site-packages\cx_Freeze\finder.py", line 268, in > _import_module
module = self._internal_import_module(name, deferred_imports)
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File > "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.11_qbz5n2kfra8> p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python311\site-packages\cx_Freeze\finder.py", line 355, in > _internal_import_module
module = self._load_module(
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File > "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.11_qbz5n2kfra8> p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python311\site-packages\cx_Freeze\finder.py", line 380, in > _load_module
spec = importlib.machinery.PathFinder.find_spec(name, path)
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File " ", line 1516, in find_spec
File " ", line 1279, in init
File " ", line 1295, in _get_parent_path
AttributeError: module 'cv2.gapi.wip' has no attribute 'path'. Did you mean: 'name'?


Hi there. Can you provide the whole output of the error you get?

@lexabug I linked to a google doc with the whole error in it

@s.eyal don't do that. Post the error message in the question itself as formatted text

@juanpa.arrivillaga I had a weird formatting issue when uploading the text to here but its done now
